# Nav Bar on Site not clickable

Tags: html, onclick, navbar

I have recently picked up a new client with two websites. I built one of their sites, but have no real involvement with their other site. Their old site has been up ans running since 2012, and has had no changes made to it. Out of the blue, their nav buttons are no longer clickable. I've tried to look into it, but to be honest I am pretty new and not sure how to deal with code I did not create.

Screencast of code from the site. 
http://screencast.com/t/v8UuHhDEpI

Actual site. 
www.desertweed.com

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a log of the changes to the code (if there were any)? If there were no changes to the code, was there a change in the browsers used, etc?

Comment: can you at least post a link to the live site so we can look?

Comment: Lately, there have been some drastic changes to the browsers.  Firefox less affected for now.  I looked at your screenshot.  Doesn't tell much other than the nav buttons are in table format.  Some div (perhaps with width in percentage must be covering the buttons, and therefore, they have become un-clickable.  Just a guess.

Comment: Updated post with actual site url. there was no changes to the code... but I have been able to go on it using chrome about a month ago.. maybe a little longer.

Answer (score 0):

`menu.js` consists of this code to create the menu. You cannot wrap a table data cell `<td>` in a `<form>`. You can wrap the `<input>` in the form inside the `<td>`.

```
document.write('<DIV id=menu>');
document.write('<TABLE cellpadding=0 cellspacing=1 border=0 bgcolor="#000000" width="100%"><tr><td width="30" background="picts/button.gif">');
document.write('<IMG SRC="picts/spacer.gif" HEIGHT="5" WIDTH="30" border="0"><BR>');

document.write('</td><form action="index.html"><td>');
document.write('<input type="submit" value=" Home " onmouseover="this.className=\'buttonon\'" onmouseout="this.className=\'button\'" class="button"><br>');

document.write('</td></form><form action="ag.htm"><td>');
document.write('<input type="submit" value="Agriculture" onmouseover="this.className=\'buttonon\'" onmouseout="this.className=\'button\'" class="button"><br>');

document.write('</td></form><form action="indust.htm"><td>');
document.write('<input type="submit" value="Industrial" onmouseover="this.className=\'buttonon\'" onmouseout="this.className=\'button\'" class="button"><br>');

//document.write('</td></form><form action="photos.htm"><td>');
//document.write('<input type="submit" value="Photos" //onmouseover="this.className=\'buttonon\'" //onmouseout="this.className=\'button\'" class="button"><br>');

document.write('<!-- COPY THE NEXT TWO LINES AND PASTE ABOVE THIS LINE TO ADD A BUTTON -->');

document.write('</td></form><form action="msds.htm"><td>');
document.write('<input type="submit" value="MSDS & Labels" onmouseover="this.className=\'buttonon\'" onmouseout="this.className=\'button\'" class="button"><br>');


document.write('</td></form><form action="contact.htm"><td>');
document.write('<input type="submit" value="Contact" onmouseover="this.className=\'buttonon\'" onmouseout="this.className=\'button\'" class="button"><br>');

document.write('</td></form>');
document.write('<td WIDTH="99%" background="picts/button.gif">');
document.write('&nbsp;<br>');
document.write('</td></tr></table></DIV>');
```

Like this:

```
document.write('</td><td><form action="index.html">');
document.write('<input type="submit" value=" Home " onmouseover="this.className=\'buttonon\'" onmouseout="this.className=\'button\'" class="button"><br>');

document.write('</form></td><td><form action="ag.htm">');
```

Now all that being said. These should not be tables, they should not be inputs, they should not be forms, and they should not be created by Javascript. This is outdated by over a decade.

Comment: Thank you Alejalapeno! I got them to at least be clickable ... but now there is a black bar underneath that doesnt look good. Honestly, this site is not worth my time.. I just want to help fix it for them because I'm a nice person. Any idea on how to make the black bar go away?

Comment: @jennifern I would usually never condone this but just add `style="margin:0"` into every form. So `<form action="index.html" style="margin:0">` and so on.

Comment: @jennifern Feel free to mark the answer as the correct answer if it helped.